# Correct way to parse php object array for Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to fill a dropdown using Ajax and PHP with JQuery. For some reason, I always get a Parse JSON Error.

**JS file**

```
function loadRolesToDropDown() {
    var url = 'controller/get_all_roles.php';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) {
            var len = data.length;
            $("#roledropdown").empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                var roleId = data[i]['roleId'];
                var roleName = data[i]['roleName'];
                $("#roledropdown").append("<option value='" + roleId + "'>" + roleName + "</option>");
            }
        },
        error: function (x, e) {
            if (x.status == 0) {
                alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
            } else if (x.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested URL not found.');
            } else if (x.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error.');
            } else if (e == 'parsererror') {
                alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
            } else if (e == 'timeout') {
                alert('Request Time out.');
            } else {
                alert('Unknown Error.\n' + x.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**get_all_roles.php**

```
$roleDaoImpl = new RoleDaoImpl($pdo);

$roleDaoImpl->getAllRoles();
```

Implementation of `getAllRoles()`

```
function getAllRoles()
{
    $roleList[] = "";
    try {
        $SQL = "CALL getAllRoles()";
        $sp_getAllRoles = $this->connection->prepare($SQL);
        $sp_getAllRoles->execute();
        $resultSet = $sp_getAllRoles->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
            $roleId = $row['role_id'];
            $roleName = $row['role_name'];
            $roleList[] = array("roleId" => $roleId, "roleName" => $roleName);
        }
        echo json_encode($roleList);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
      die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

And when I tried to echo what's return by `json_encode($roleList);` I get the ff:

```
["",{"roleId":1,"roleName":"Administrator"},{"roleId":2,"roleName":"Teacher"},{"roleId":3,"roleName":"Student"}]
```

What is the correct way to parse the php object array return by php?

Thank you.

Comment: The JSON you have shown seems to be perfectly valid ... So what exact error are you getting, and what is the actual data it is referring to? (Check via your browser dev tools, network panel, what the _exact_ response for this request looks like.)

Comment: @CBroe I get the error from this line of code `else if (e == 'parsererror') {
                alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
            }`

Answer (score 0):

In your php function getAllRoles

```
function getAllRoles()
{
    $roleList[] = ""; // -> should be $roleList = [];
```

Comment: I tried this but got the same error on parsing. This is what I got when I changed `$roleList[] = "";` to `$roleList = [];` 
`[{"roleId":1,"roleName":"Administrator"},{"roleId":2,"roleName":"Teacher"},{"roleId":3,"roleName":"Student"}]`

Comment: Try to change these lines:

var roleId = data[i]['roleId'];
                
var roleName = data[i]['roleName'];

to
var roleId = data[i].roleId;

                var roleName = data[i].roleName;

or try:

var role = JSON.parse(data[i]);

and use role.roleId and role.roleName

Answer (score 0):

```
In your get_all_roles.php if you are getting such type of result from query then this code will work

$resultSet = array(0=>array('role_id'=>1,'role_name'=>'Administrator'),1=>array('role_id'=>2,'role_name'=>'Teacher'),2=>array('role_id'=>3,'role_name'=>'Student'));

foreach ($resultSet as $row) {
 $roleId = $row['role_id'];
 $roleName = $row['role_name'];
 $roleList[] = array("roleId" => $roleId, "roleName" => $roleName);
}
echo json_encode($roleList);
```